# Excluding a specific word in OCaml RegEx

Tags: regex, ocaml, flowtype

I wrote this regular expression in JavaScript:

```
node_modules\/(?!react\-hot).*-loader.*
```

The idea is to match every string like `node_modules/babel-loader` or `node_modules/css-loader` but exclude `node_modules/react-hot-loader`.

[Here is a regex101 link of this working](https://regex101.com/r/0zHgFc/1).

(The context here is that I am writing a [Flowtype config file](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/ignore/)).

I am trying to test the same RegEx in OCaml but I am not being successful:

```
# let regexp = Str.regexp "node_modules/(?!react-hot).*-loader.*";;
val regexp : Str.regexp = <abstr>
# Str.string_match regexp "node_modules/babel-loader" 0 ;;
- : bool = false
# Str.string_match regexp "node_modules/react-hot-loader" 0 ;;
- : bool = false
```

I don't understand why the `babel-loader` string is not matching the RegEx because this very same RegEx works in RegEx 101 for JavaScript RegExes.

I understand that OCaml Regular Expressions do not follow the same standard as JavaScript Regular Expressions. However, after reading about OCaml Regular Expressions in the official documentation [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html#TYPEregexp), I couldn't find anything that could cause this difference in behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `!` is not a special character in OCaml regular expressions. So it seems you are using an unsupported feature.

Comment: Oops, I just re-read the official documentation I linked to in my question and it appears you are right. It seems like OCaml RegEx does not support negation which means that what I'm trying to do might not be possible at all. I think there should be another way.

Comment: Negation does not increase the expressiveness. That means there is an OCaml regular expression that does what you want, albeit possibly not a simple or nice one. I don't know why OCaml regular expressions do not support negation, but a possible good reason is that negation causes combinatorial explosion (state space exponentiation).

Answer (score 0):

`Str` is a good old OCaml regexp library in the POSIX style syntax.  It does not support PCRE and its extensions.  There is no advantage to use `Str` today, except that it is included in the OCaml compiler.

You may want to try `pcre-ocaml` https://github.com/mmottl/pcre-ocaml which fully supports PCRE.

There is even another OCaml regexp library called `ocaml-re` https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re .  It is newer and written purely in OCaml, and supports multiple regexp syntax flavors (POSIX, PCRE, glob), but it seems to me that the negation lookahead `(?!..)` is not supported for now (I tried to parse your regexp but it rejected `(?!..)` part).

Comment: How these libraries can be used in flowconfig?